# 404 error from APT for ffmulticonverter PPA

Tags: apt

I'm getting this error when am trying to update using command
 `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Fetched 1,338 kB in 38s (34.9 kB/s)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ffmulticonverter/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ffmulticonverter/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

The admin of the server has removed the package either permanently or temporarily. Please try again after sometime, if the error persists then, please untick the ppa from Softwares & Updates > Other Softwares and update again.

Thank You!